# Android 2.3 SDP Parser?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, sdp

which file is responsible for sdp parsing in gingerbread?
i want to customize it for adding some additional flags?
is there any links available for it.then can you please share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [android.net.sip.SimpleSessionDescription](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=voip/java/android/net/sip/SimpleSessionDescription.java;h=29166dc5462596964bc01d5fd3b53aea84b68804;hb=HEAD) for SDP string.
But it's an internal, so you might copy this.